# Is there a way to get a notification when a dialog opens or closes?

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I have to do modifications to a very old and complex MFC App.

At the moment there is the need to notify via an external interface when a dialog (no matter modal or nonmodal) is opened or closed and to count the opened dialogs.

To do this before every `DoModal()` and `Create` is no option because there are also DLLs involved that can open dialogs and cannot be changed.

So is there a way to be notified, if a dialog opens?

And is there a way to be notified, if a dialog is closed?

TIA Michael

Comment: [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/winevents-infrastructure).

Comment: seems to be very promising. I will give it a try.

Comment: Do you know, what events I need to look at? With EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE and EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY I get many notifications about child windows like buttons or edit controls, but nothing seems to be the dialog itself. And there is not a destroy for every create. EVENT_SYSTEM_DIALOGSTART and EVENT_SYSTEM_DIALOGEND don't give any notification at all.

Comment: You might want to tag @IInspectable if you want his attention to your comment. Otherwise no one knows you were directing your statement to them.

Comment: `EVENT_SYSTEM_DIALOGSTART` and `EVENT_SYSTEM_DIALOGEND` are the events that should work just fine. If they don't work for you, you might have to use a [CBT hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks#wh_cbt) instead.